# Unreal Engine blueprint node and pin extension

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am new to Unreal Engine and was trying to customize my own blueprint according to some tutorial online. However, I did not know which function to call when trying to extend a node and a pin. What I am trying to achieve is as below:

[image]

There are 2 parts here that I could not figure it out.

1. How to extend the "Handle Location" variable, so that I could obtain the X:0, Y:0, Z:0 box as seen above?
2. How to create the pin extension box, where one node is able to connect to another 2 nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend a node pin. Pin is either an output or input. What you probably wanted to say is "split struct pin". You can do that by right-clicking on that particular pin and choosing "split struct pin". To reverse this, you can do the same and choose "recombine struct pin". For vectors, you can drag out the pin and choose "break vector" node in the node search. Similarly for rotators, "break rotator". 
**In short, click on an empty space in the same blueprint and search for "Get Handle Location". This gives you the reference to the vector you want to access. Then, drag the yellow pin and search for "break vector". Now you can access each axis location separately.**

Keep in mind that you cannot access any variable of any blueprint in the game just by searching for it. Here you can because it is in the same blueprint. Otherwise, you need to make blueprints communicate together.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to splitting the vector pin on the node pin via RMB as in [Marek S.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42938142/2267503) you can also LMB and to add a **Break Vector** node.

If I read you right, the extension box you are looking for is called a **reroute node** which is a pin dropped at the end of a wire. You can pull more wires off this pin or move them around to clean up the wire paths. Reroute nodes can be added by double clicking on a wire or by LMB while dragging a wire and creating a **reroute node** that way.

FWIW you can pull more than one wire off a pin in most cases. Also, as cgardner points out the search bar in the action node selection popup (drag wire or LMB in blueprint editor) is your best friend. Type "bre" to filter down to the Break nodes, "rer" will select the reroute node.

Answer (score -1):

Both of those boxes you highlight above are Vector Addition nodes. If you drag off a Vector pin, you should be able to search for "vector + vector" in the search box that appears!

It looks like this:
[image: Vector + Vector]

Generally, when you drag off a pin, the box that appears will contain all the usual things you can do with a pin of that type. The search box is also quite smart, if you type "vector add" instead of "vector + vector," you will still get the vector + vector result!

Good luck!

Comment: Nice answer but to a different question?